# Spring Boot application does not start with logback EvaluatorFilter and Janino library inside application lib folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logback-classic, janino

I have a spring-boot based application deployed in tomcat. It uses logback-classic for logging. logback.xml is kept externally inside $TOMCAT_HOME/conf folder and logback.xml is referred using logging.config from a config properties file which is also at the same location.

Recently we added the following filter to filter out some logs

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
     <evaluator>
           <expression>return message.contains("SOMESTRING")</expression>
      </evaluator>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
            <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
```

The above filter requires below library

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When we build and deploy the application janino library is downloaded inside application lib folder, we checked it exists. But when we are starting the application though tomcat start successfully the application does not deploy. No log shows up also if we try to access the application using browser it says 504 bad gateway. We need a solution for this please help us out.

We copied the Janino library inside tomcat lib folder and it works. But we don't want to do that. Also logback-classic and logback-core jars are present inside application lib folder, inside tomcat webapps.

We except application should start with a started message in the logs. But we don't see that, also application does not respond when invoked.

Comment: Are all of Logback's jars in your war file's `WEB-INF/lib` or are there some Logback classes in jars in Tomcat's lib folder? If you're not sure, you could start Tomcat with `-verbose:class` to verify from where Logback's classes are being loaded.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks for suggesting. We resolved the issue. We had two applications deployed in same tomcat instance and both are using the same logback.xml from conf folder although they have own logback.xml. As already stated its overridden via logging.config. But the filter was required in one of the modules so we added the Janino dependency in that module only. Due to that first application was starting successfully. Second one failed to start. Now when we added Janino dependency in 2nd module it worked fine also the filter started working.